# How to export and load the notes as a text some kind of file file (javascript)

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById('add-note').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var note = prompt('Enter your note:');
    if (note) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.textContent = note;
        document.getElementById('notes-list').appendChild(li);
    }
});
```

I am trying to make a note section for my webpage and i want to export the notes as a text or some kind of file and also load it back. This is offline.

Comment: You could create an array from your data and export it as a CSV. See the duplicate for more details on that. If this does not meet your needs, then please edit the question to show much more context around the expected behaviour, and also the code you wrote to reach that goal.

Comment: i am a beginner so i don't know much about js